# Is there any way to wrap any overloaded function into a function object?

Tags: c++, function, functor, overload-resolution

I was inspired from the C++ Ranges style for creating overloads of `operator()` inside the class and I found it very useful in many cases:

- Can be passed as an argument directly like lambda but unlike overloaded functions.
- Protected from ADL.
- Preventing from specifying template arguments (closely, but `.template operator()<...>`)

For easy cases, I can handle it manually:

For overloaded function:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename G>
constexpr auto compose(F&& f, G&& g) {
    return [
        f = std::forward<F>(f),
        g = std::forward<G>(g)
    ]<typename... Ts>(Ts&&... args) {
        if constexpr (std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<G, Ts...>>) {
            std::invoke_r<void>(g, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
            return std::invoke(f);
        } else {
            return std::invoke(f, std::invoke(g, std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
        }
    };
}

template <typename F, typename... Fs>
constexpr auto compose(F&& f, Fs&&... fs) {
    return compose(std::forward<F>(f), compose(std::forward<Fs>(fs)...));
}
```

For Function Object:

```cpp
namespace functors {
  struct compose_fn {
    template <typename... Fs>
    constexpr auto operator()(Fs&&... fs) const noexcept {
      return ::compose(std::forward<Fs>(fs)...);
    }
  };
  inline constexpr compose_fn compose {};
}
```

Where I could use to pass it inside `std::apply`:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N, typename F>
constexpr auto func_power(F f) {
    auto return_identity_ = [&f]<std::size_t I>(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>) noexcept {
        return f;
    };

    auto tup_ = [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return std::make_tuple(return_identity_(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{})...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});

    /// apply:
    return std::apply(functors::compose, tup_);
}
```

Whereas the global `compose` can't be passed because it's ambiguous.

The only thing I could get as general is this one:

```cpp
[]<typename... Ts>(Ts&&... args){
  return some_overloaded_function(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

However, the following constraints will depend on the `some_overloaded_function`.

Is there a **general** way to wrap any overloaded functions into function objects by just implementing 1 tool (function, function object, etc.)?

Comment: you are looking for a "tool" that creates something like your `functors::compose` for any overload set, not just for `compose` ?

Comment: yes, I was looking for a general "tool" that can wrap overloaded function

Comment: I am afraid your `functors::compose` is as general as you can get. An overload set cannot be passed around so you need some boilerplate. Maybe this could make a case for macros, but maybe I am wrong and there is a nicer way

Comment: *"the following constraints will depend on the `some_overloaded_function`"* Are you looking for SFINAE `[]<typename... Ts>(Ts&&... args) -> decltype(some_overloaded_function(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)) { return some_overloaded_function(std::forward<Ts>(args)...)}` (and you can also add `noexcept` specification).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you need a macro (unfortunately)

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int plus(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

double plus(double a, double b){
    return a + b;
}

#define Lambdafy(fn) ([](auto && ... args)->decltype(auto){ return fn(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);})

int main(){
  
    
    std::vector<int> input = {1,2,3};

    auto r = input | std::views::transform(std::bind_front(Lambdafy(plus),1));

    for(auto i : r)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6cjPbEKsz